# Environment variables in deployed Next.js Serverless App

Tags: next.js, amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework

So in my project I have one **.env** file on the *root* of the project, which has default environment variables for all stages.
Then I have *config* folder where I keep environment and serverless.yml file for each environment (**.env.staging , .env.production etc..**):

Like this:

```
-root:
 -config:
  -staging:
    .env.staging
    serverless.yml
```

When I run:

```
env-cmd -f config/staging/.env.staging next build
```

and then:

```
next start
```

It loads all the environment variables .env + .env.staging. Which is good and it works perfectly but only locally.

This is my serverless.yml file :

```
my-app-staging:
  component: "@sls-next/serverless-component@1.18.0"
  inputs:
    nextConfigDir: ../../
    bucketName: my-app-staging
    cloudfront:
      comment: my-app-staging
```

So for staging deployment I run this:

```
env-cmd -f config/staging/.env.staging next build && cd config/staging && sls
```

On the deployed version, All environment variables from root .env are available but **NOT** from .env.staging.

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

So it happens that when running the `sls` command to deploy the app, it is a different environment that serverless uses. In order to pass that environment on serverless build you should pass the desired environment.

In this case the deploy script should look like this:

```
"build:staging": "env-cmd -f environment/staging/.env.staging next build",
"deploy:staging": "npm run build:staging && cd config/staging && env-cmd -f .env.staging sls"
```